# JQuery trigger("change") on Completion of another trigger("change"), where .change includes ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have various .change jquery methods in order to populate one dropdown using data from another dropdown; this works correctly.

Now, I am having trouble automatically *firing* these .changes using .trigger("change") in an explicit function. This explicit function should automatically select the correct dropdown items such that after the first trigger's ajax completes, the next should execute etc.

```
function populate(id, block, chapter) {
    $("#Chapters").val(chapter).trigger("change");
    $("#Blocks").val(block).trigger("change");
    $("#IDs").val(id);
}
```

Here are the ajax powered methods for populating the respective dropdowns:
(NOTE: I have used async:false to try mitigate my waiting problem; i see that this is most likely not the solution and that the solution may lie somewhere in my explicit function shown above)

```
    $('#Chapters').change(
    function () {
        var selectedVal = $(this).val();
        $.ajax("/Library/GetBlocksByChapter", {
            async: false,
            data: { "chapterId": selectedVal },
            type: "POST",
            success:
            function (data) {
                $("#Blocks").empty().append("<option value='0'>--Select a Block--</option>");
                $("#IDs").empty().append("<option value='0'>--Please Select a Block First--</option>");
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $("#Blocks").append("<option class='form-control' value='" + value["dbid"] + "'>" + value["name"] + "</option>");
                }
                );
            }
        });
    }
        );
```

---

```
    $('#Blocks').change(
function () {
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    $.ajax("/Library/GetIDsByBlock", {
        async: false,
        data: { "blockId": selectedVal },
        type: "POST",
        success:
        function (data) {
            $("#IDs").empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                $("#IDs").append("<option class='form-control' value='" + value["dbid"] + "'>" + value["name"] + "</option>");
            }
            );
        }
    });
}
    );
```

---

To make things a bit clearer: I have 3 dropdowns, the first one populates the second one etc.
I have a few buttons on the page that call the method *populate(id, block, chapter)* in order to auto select the dropdowns; where id,block,chapter are values that are populated in the dropdowns via ajax.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Looks like you're trying to manually trigger a *change* on an option (or something?) rather than the select. I think you might just need to change to ` $("#Blocks").trigger("change");` unless I'm reading it wrong.

Comment: Sorry I never included the html but I am triggering change on a select tag. #Blocks #Chapters and #IDs are all select tags

Comment: Right, but by calling $("#Blocks").val() you're actually calling a method of the jQuery-wrapped select tag that returns the selected option. This means that when you chain the method call to trigger(), that's being run on the option and not the select tag.

Comment: @brianvaughn Cool, learning new things :)  Although i can confirm that the first one, `$("#Chapters").val(chapter).trigger("change");` is working.

Comment: I see. Maybe I'm misreading then. If you get the chance to toss up a plunker, I could take a look at the HTMl maybe.